# Stanford NLP named entity recognition libraries for biomedical entities

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp

Where can I find Stanford NLP named entity recognition libraries for genes, proteins, hormones, transcription factors, neurotransmitters, cytokines, biomarkers,  epigenetic markers, enzymes, RNAs, organs, cells, drugs, and diseases?

Answer (score 2):

In a nutshell: To my best knowledge, no BioNER models are (easily?) available for the Stanford tools. If you are looking for pre-trained models for biomedical entities, your best bets are (in alphabetical order):

- [ABNER](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~bsettles/abner/)
- [BANNER](http://banner.sourceforge.net/)
- [ChemSpot](https://www.informatik.hu-berlin.de/de/forschung/gebiete/wbi/resources/chemspot/chemspot)
- (Apache) [cTAKES](https://ctakes.apache.org/)
- [GeneTUKit](https://omictools.com/genetukit-tool)
- [GENIATagger](https://github.com/saffsd/geniatagger/)
- [GNAT](http://gnat.sourceforge.net/)
- [Linnaeus](http://linnaeus.sourceforge.net/)
- (The) [NCBI Taggers collection](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/research/bionlp/Tools/)
- [Neji2](https://github.com/BMDSoftware/neji)
- [OpenDMAP](http://opendmap.sourceforge.net/)
- training your own tagger ...

But none of those are built using the Stanford CoreNLP library, and not all are Java-based, either...

Comment: Oh, cool.  Thanks for the list fnl.  ABNER looks promising.  It will take a while to investigate all these.  I really don't want to be in the business of laborious training.  I've been reading this paper which claims to be able to do NER with deep learning methods, ie no training. https://arxiv.org/pdf/1103.0398.pdf  After all, we can learn just by reading so why can't our algorithms?

Comment: "King" Collobert's NLP (almost) from Scratch paper isn't about an unsupervised approach. And deep learning needs training, too - in fact, much, much, much more training (time/calculations) than any other machine learning method (hence the GPUs...). So you still need to train a classifier against labeled data (of which you also need more for successful deep learning!). So you also will need at least one good GPU to run that stuff fast and repeatedly to tune your setup. But if you have the time and resources, its always a fun thing to do (training your own tagger)!

Comment: Well that is really discouraging, if true.  I thought the whole point of "deep learning" was the ability to learn with no need to curate the input.  Does IBM Watson need guidance too?  My 8 year old daughter doesn't.

Comment: Anything in python from that list?

Comment: @GrimSqueaker: In a word: no. Astonishingly, there are no good, ready-made BioNER tools/models in Python around and almost everything is Java-based in the BioNLP world. At best, GeniaTagger and [NerSuite](http://nersuite.nlplab.org/) (which is a wrapper around GeniaTagger and improves its NER performance) are based on C++, so you could come up with a Python wrapper for them.

Comment: If my specialty and capabilities included writing a Python wrapper, or munging the "treebank" data for retraining, I wouldn't need to be asking about anything already written in Python :(